# how to decrease speech rate in google text to speech

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I tried several ways to lower the speech rate in google tts android.

```
 myTTS.setSpeechRate(1/2);
```

this is not working. This produces the default speed. its not accepting 0.5 (type is float). Someone help

Comment: Try `setSpeechRate(0.5f)`

Comment: That worked out, Thanks :)

Comment: Good. Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the float value correctly:

```
myTTS.setSpeechRate(0.5f);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use float in this way. This is a sample to adjust the Pitch and SpeechRate

```
myTTS.setPitch((float)0.7);
myTTS.setSpeechRate((float)0.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set float value as argument

e.g. 1

```
float tempo = 1/2;
myTTS.setSpeechRate(0.5f);
```

e.g. 2

```
float tempo = 0.5f;
myTTS.setSpeechRate(tempo);
```

e.g. 3

```
myTTS.setSpeechRate(0.5f);
```

e.g. 4

```
myTTS.setSpeechRate((float)(1/2));
```